# AWS batchGetItem NSInvalidArgumentException JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to get some rows from DynamoDB in a Swift application. At the very last line in my code below I get a NSInvalidArgumentException.  I think it must be because my request is not formatted correctly, but I don't know what is wrong.  In the docs ([batch operation sample](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/batch-operation-document-api-java.html)) for the java sdk they use TableKeysAndAttributes, which doesn't seem to exist in the iOS SDK.

Here is my code:

```
 var venueIdAttribute = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    venueIdAttribute.N = "2164156"

    var venueIdCondition = AWSDynamoDBCondition()
    venueIdCondition.comparisonOperator = .EQ // Hash Key must always be Equals
    venueIdCondition.attributeValueList = [venueIdAttribute]

    var startDateAttribute = AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue()
    var startString = String(format:"%1.0f", lastSyncDate.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    startDateAttribute.N = String(format:"%1.0f", lastSyncDate.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)

    var dateCondition = AWSDynamoDBCondition()
    dateCondition.comparisonOperator = .GT
    dateCondition.attributeValueList = [startDateAttribute];

    var keysArray : NSArray = [["venueId" : venueIdCondition, "dateInterval" : dateCondition]]
    var tableDict : NSDictionary = ["Keys":keysArray]
    var requestMap : NSDictionary = ["myTable":tableDict]

    var request : AWSDynamoDBBatchGetItemInput = AWSDynamoDBBatchGetItemInput()        
    request.requestItems = requestMap
    request.returnConsumedCapacity = AWSDynamoDBReturnConsumedCapacity.Total

    var response : BFTask = dynamoDB.batchGetItem(request)  // This is synchronous
```

Here is the error:

2014-12-18 13:23:17.002 TouchDashboard[8066:503166] +[**NSDictionaryI JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10a9930e8
2014-12-18 13:23:17.010 TouchDashboard[8066:503166] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[__NSDictionaryI JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10a9930e8'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a6ebf35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c5b1bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a6f2f4d +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a64b27c ___forwarding_** + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a64ae18 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   TouchDashboard                      0x0000000109b1176a -[MTLJSONAdapter initWithModel:] + 490
    6   TouchDashboard                      0x0000000109b0fc47 +[MTLJSONAdapter JSONDictionaryFromModel:] + 87
    7   TouchDashboard                      0x00000001099a47c5 +[AZModelUtility JSONDictionaryFromMapMTLDictionary:] + 517
    8   TouchDashboard                      0x0000000109a91c5b **59+[AWSDynamoDBBatchGetItemInput requestItemsJSONTransformer]_block_invoke_2 + 75
    9   TouchDashboard                      0x0000000109b21718 -[MTLReversibleValueTransformer reverseTransformedValue:] + 88
    10  TouchDashboard                      0x0000000109b11b90 __32-[MTLJSONAdapter JSONDictionary]_block_invoke + 480
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a62d766 __65-[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 102
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a62d66c -[__NSDictionaryM enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 204
    13  TouchDashboard                      0x0000000109b1192c -[MTLJSONAdapter JSONDictionary] + 300
    14  TouchDashboard                      0x0000000109b0fc5b +[MTLJSONAdapter JSONDictionaryFromModel:] + 107
    15  TouchDashboard                      0x00000001099a6829 -[AWSDynamoDB invokeRequest:HTTPMethod:URLString:targetPrefix:operationName:outputClass:] + 313
    16  TouchDashboard                      0x00000001099a6bd9 -[AWSDynamoDB batchGetItem:] + 153
    17  TouchDashboard                      0x000000010991a0d7 _TFC14TouchDashboard14ViewController9batchSyncfS0_FT_T_ + 10663
    18  TouchDashboard                      0x0000000109917349 _TFC14TouchDashboard14ViewController11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ + 1161
    19  TouchDashboard                      0x0000000109917462 _TToFC14TouchDashboard14ViewController11viewDidLoadfS0_FT_T_ + 34
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010b41ea90 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 738
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010b41ec8e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010b33dca9 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010b33e041 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010b34a72c -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    25  UIKit                               0x000000010b2f5061 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2628
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010b2f7d2c -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1350
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010b2f6bf2 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    28  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010ebe92a3 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a62153c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 12
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a617285 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a616a43 __CFRunLoopRun + 851
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a616486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    33  UIKit                               0x000000010b2f6669 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    34  UIKit                               0x000000010b2f9420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    35  TouchDashboard                      0x000000010992ba2e top_level_code + 78
    36  TouchDashboard                      0x000000010992ba6a main + 42
    37  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010cd8b145 start + 1
    38  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AWSDynamoDBBatchGetItemInput`'s `requestItems` property needs to be a dictionary of the following key/value pair:

`NSString` (a table name) : [`AWSDynamoDBKeysAndAttributes`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Classes/AWSDynamoDBKeysAndAttributes.html) (`KeysAndAttributes`)

Currently, you are passing an instance of `NSDictionary` as a value. Once you update your code snippet to use `AWSDynamoDBKeysAndAttributes`, it should work.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my error!  But now I get another one.  I'll create another question for it-- please check it out Yosuke!